# Are the relations preserved when transferring data from a relational DB to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, relational-database, amazon-rds, object-oriented-database

There are [options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html) for transferring a DB snapshot from a relational database to S3 in AWS.

But S3 is an object store, so it only stores files (e.g. parquet).

Are the relationships (like keys) between tables in the relational DB somehow carried over to S3? Can queries still be made against the files in S3 that would allow joins to be made between tables?

Answer (score 1):

There are no "keys" like foreign key, primary key in the exported parquet files in S3, but you can still query the the exported data directly through tools like Amazon Athena or Amazon Redshift Spectrum. For more information on using Athena to read Parquet data, see Parquet SerDe in the Amazon Athena User Guide. For more information on using Redshift Spectrum to read Parquet data, see COPY from columnar data formats in the Amazon Redshift Database Developer Guide.

The time it takes for the export to complete depends on the data stored in the database. For example, tables with well distributed numeric primary key or index columns will export the fastest. Tables that don't contain a column suitable for partitioning and tables with only one index on a string-based column will take longer because the export uses a slower single threaded process. For example if a table got a numeric pk and got 100,000 rows, during export data will be "partitioned" in a few portion, each portion are a directory in the S3 bucket, so that when you query data in Athena/Redshift spectrum with that id, AWS know what buckets to scan to get the data and thus improve performance and speed.

In summary, after data exported as columnar format like parquet in S3, you can do inplace query by Athena, load the data to redshift or data store for more analytics, etc..